# Wi-fi localisation using AMCL

Tags: ros, navigation, wifi, localilzation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are working on a project whereby we are attempting to localize the robot within the map using the received wi-fi signal strength ID (RSSID). We have had a look through the amcl_node.cpp file and have a pretty general idea of how it functions.
Just wondering how do we achieve localization solely on the basis of RSSID?
The way we are trying to make it work is by receiving the goal co-ordinates from the user and the turtlebot navigating to the goal using the map and the wi-fi signal strength. Do we need to build a wi-fi signal strength map and then feed this through to amcl?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/150691/wi-fi-localisation-using-amcl/) by [aviprobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/6004/aviprobo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-04-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AMCL is written to localize based on laser scan matching. I don't think there's any way that you could use it to localize based on wireless signal strength.

The research I've seen that does localization based on Wifi signal strength didn't have particularly high accuracy; Wifi localization is still mostly a research topic.

If you're writing your own algorithms to localize based on wireless signal strength, you'll want to write your own node which computes the global pose, presumably based on your research, subtracts off the odom->base_link transform, and publishes a correction transform from map->odom ; this is the appropriate way to provide a global pose to the ROS navigation system. You may be able to take some inspiration for how to do this from the AMCL code.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-02-07**:
@aviprobo - So what did you do finally? Kindly update the response. And @ahendrix - we want to pass on initial rough co-ordinate to our turtlebot using Wi-Fi signal strength. Any idea about how to go about that? Generally, initial coordinates and goals are given using RVIZ but we want to use Wi-Fi.